# Postgres Database not available in ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, postgresql, ado.net

I am trying to create entities from a postgres database using the Visual Studio ADO.NET Entity Data Model, however Postgres Database is not listed as one of the data sources.  I have installed dotconnect for PostgreSQL and still the option to create a model/schema of the database is not available.  I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Could anyone help please?  I need to query database entities from my C# application.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.

As you can read in the requirements of the [dotconnect emf tutorial](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/articles/tutorial_ef.html) you have to install the Professional addition:

"Note that Entity Framework support is not available in Standard Edition of dotConnect for PostgreSQL."

If you have that version follow the tutorial.

Hope this helps.

[Edit]

I found a different solution with npgsql [here](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html).

I made it work with version 3.0.7 (all npgsql components!) which seems to be the latest version supporting the emf stuff.